# FastAPI and SqlAlchemy dataerror related to dates

Tags: postgresql, web, sqlalchemy, fastapi

anyone have any idea why do i get this error while using postgressql + sqlalchemy + fastapi, while i try to commit model to a database?
Debugging the FastAPI application timestamp field is a datetime field.

```
__tablename__ = "TimeMap"

timestamp = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True, index=True)
key = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
value = Column(String, default=False)



sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat) invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "string"
LINE 1: ...-28T17:30:38.463000+00:00'::timestamptz, 'string', 'string')
                                                              ^

[SQL: INSERT INTO "TimeMap" (timestamp, key, value) VALUES (%(timestamp)s, %(key)s, %(value)s)]
[parameters: {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 28, 17, 30, 38, 463000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'key': 'string', 'value': 'string'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input format for the `timestamp` value is **invalid**. It appears that you are passing a **string** value to the timestamp column, but it is expecting a `DateTime` object.

To fix this, you need to ensure that the timestamp value you are passing is a valid `DateTime` object. You can create a `DateTime` object using the datetime module in Python like this

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

# create a datetime object
utc_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))

session.add(TimeMap(timestamp=utc_time, key='string', value='string'))
session.commit()
```